# UWP App crash in release mode in Windows.UI.Xaml.dll

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, crash, uwp-xaml

So, this had been 4th day of me hunting down this one bug.

I was working on my app and in a past 2 released of my app. I ended up submit app to Microsoft Store that crash on start up.

My project is built using Windows Template Studio with slightly modify and using Microsft UI Library (Microsoft.UI.Xaml) that released a few weeks ago. But the issue might not relate to it.

I was always testing my app in debug mode and everything went fine but whenever I build in release mode it is just crash on startup with this error:

[image: This error right here]

(Unhandled exception at 0x6587AA49 (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) in app.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.)

I tried changing my app to open into other pages and it work just fine. But when I move to home page it is this error right here showed up. ^

Here is what's my [homepage code](https://github.com/ray1997/JustRememberUWP/blob/LatestRelease/JustRemember/Views/MainPage.xaml) look like

Basically, it is a navigation view from Microsoft.UI library. With sub pages.

As my app is loaded, I can see a text on the sub page, my guees the issue might be somewhere from [this page](https://github.com/ray1997/JustRememberUWP/blob/LatestRelease/JustRemember/Views/SubHome/MemoSub.xaml)

Sorry, if the issue seems too vague. But I can't narrow down to specific code line and post it here.

If you need to clone the project, here is the link: https://github.com/ray1997/JustRememberUWP/tree/LatestRelease

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVM, I was found out on my MainPage, right when the page was loaded. I was navigated to the same pages multiple times and it cause the app to get a StackoverflowException and crash.